# Is there a built-in way to use a git hash based on its .git/objects path?

Tags: bash, git

I'm interested in playing around with `git cat-file` in order to better understand Git's object model. One thing that's a bit of a nuisance in the Git Bash shell is copying a hash (especially as I'm not used to Git Bash's C&P shortcuts.)

Let's say I have a hash abc123... etc., stored like this:

```
ls .git/objects/ab/c123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abcd
```

I can use sed and such to extract the hash portion of the path:

```
ls .git/objects/ab/c123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abcd | sed -e 's|.git/objects/||' -e 's|/||'
```

But I still need to navigate to the hash and paste the sed command in and so on. It's not a major annoyance but for the time it takes me to do I might as well copy the hash manually.

The question: is there a Git built-in function which reads the path to the hash in .git/objects and outputs a useable hash? I.e.

Input:

```
.git/objects/ab/c123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abcd
```

Output:

```
abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abcd
```

Comment: Git does not expose this for $reasons, but it's trivial to do in bash itself as the loose object's name is always ${GIT_DIR}/objects/<first-two>/<remainder> and bash (and other shells) can do simple string manipulation here. Of course it's trivial to do in sed too, as you noted. But if you want to know about Git's internals, they're *documented!* Check out git-scm.org and also the source's Documentation/technical directory.

Comment: I know Git's internals are documented, that's what I've been reading. I've been experimenting from reading the documentation, because I feel like that's how I'll learn. I guess I can write a bash function to achieve this functionality if I feel like it's worth it.